# How can Tesla battery packs be so small?

Tags: battery, electric-vehicles

According its [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_S), a Tesla Model S battery pack can accumulate 100 kWh energy.

The wiki page of the [LiON batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery) shows a 100-265 kWh/kg specific energy, and [this source](https://stealthev.com/product/tesla-module/) shows a Tesla battery pack with 210 kWh/kg (thanks @Solar Mike).

Calculating these, we get the required mass of a Tesla Model S battery to $\approx$ 600 kg.

This is obviousy much more than the reality. How is it possible? What is the real mass of a battery pack in a Tesla Model S?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132115/discussion-on-question-by-peterh-how-can-tesla-battery-packs-be-so-small).

Comment: Explain what is unclear in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: yes, the calculation is roughly correct. The weightiest part of the Teslas (and other electric vehicles) is their battery pack, and yes, they weight typically more hundreds kg.

Note, only a little part of it is actually lithium (for example, only $\approx 4.4\%$ of $\rm{LiFePO_4}$) is lithium element.